# Prevent Word from Including Bullet Letter when Copying Text

Tags: microsoft-word, clipboard

I'm copying quite a bit of text from Word into a text-based application, line by line.  The word text is structured like this:

> 1. Topic
>
>    a. Item A
>
>    b. Item B

When I highlight `Item A`, copy, and then paste into the text-based application, I get `a.    Item A` rather than just `Item A` as desired.

How can I prevent Word from including the bullet letter when copying?

Comment: This behavior is the same in Outlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see that you could avoid include the numbering is to turn it off prior to copy.

[image: Word Numbers icon]

Word will generally include as much information as it can in the copy, and it is up to the recieving application to extract what information it can use.

Comment: But then I lose valuable formatting... I could solve the problem I guess by saving as a text file, but the formatting is very useful while moving data from Word to the external app.

Comment: Disabling numbering should only remove the numbering formatting - am I missing something?

Comment: Also... interestingly... if I copy the text `1. Topic`, I don't get the numbering, just `Topic`.

Comment: What is the recieving app?

Comment: When I have a lot of sub-points (say a. to p.) that sometimes are more than 1 line long (line wrapping), without the numbering, it's not easy to see which lines are a single item.

Comment: But your question is asking that the numbering isn't retained?  How would you want these items to be displayed?

Comment: I want to see the numbering/lettering in Word, but not have the lettering copied into the clipboard (numbering is already not copied into the clipboard).

Comment: My suggestion was only to disable numbering for the copy action, then put it back (ctrl-z).  Not to get rid of it entirely.

Answer (score 21):

Hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button and select the text, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it anywhere excluding the bullet letter.

Comment: This works for text that's on a single line, but not multiline.

Comment: As of March 2019, this totally works for single or multi-lines/multi-bullets, therefore this should be deemed the correct answer imo.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Only drawback of this method is that you can't use the keyboard to select (I think). It appears that Alt+Shift+<arrow keys> moves lines of text around.

Comment: Is it possible to make this the default behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Old post but had to do it today.

1. Highlight the bullet text by dragging from first letter in word to the end last word only.
2. If you go pass the last letter you will see a half empty space highlighted.
3. Drag the cursor back to end of the last letter if you also hightlight the half space.
4. Copy the line (unfortunately, only one line at a time).

That half empty space (end of each bullet) is the hidden formatting of the bullet. If you copy (double, triple clicking by default), you also copy the bullet or list number.

Comment: This only works if you stay within an application in Office (i.e. behaves the same in Outlook). Moving to another app (e.g. Notepad, or the Windows Explorer address bar, or even pasting in a command line) includes the bullet point no matter what. **Really** frustrating when you're trying to grab network paths from stuff.

Answer (score 0):

ALT select somewhat works. But it is a block select.

```
I came up with much simpler way:
copy the whole text from Word into your favorite Text editor (Notepad2-Mod, Notepad++).
Now select and  copy only text without any pesky extra chars.
```

Comment: "use a text editor" is about as unhelpful as an answer gets

Answer (score 0):

At least in Microsoft Word 2010, I can select the entire bullet text *except the first character*, which I temporarily store in my head, and copy the selection.

Then, when I want to paste the text, I simply type the character temporarily stored in my head followed by a clipboard paste. The clipboard will not contain any bullet.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all above but here is what I will prefer. Suppose you have 50 lines of texts having bullets in your doc. You also want to keep bullets in there but do not want them to be copied. Simply paste a | (pipe) between bullet and text before you start copying . This should take few seconds and then you can copy up to the pipe only :)

Answer (score -3):

File -> Word Options -> Advanced

Scroll down to the "Cut, copy, and paste" section

Turn off "Keep bullets and numbers when pasting text with Keep Text Only option

Comment: This only applies to pasting _within_ Word documents. If you copy and paste to another application this will not work.