# How to paste word item from numbered list without initial number

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste

When I copy a line from a numbered list in word 2010, if I paste it, either in word or other apps, I get the initial number as well. How do I prevent the number from getting pasted? To illustrate:

I have a list like this

1. Initial sentence
2. Second sentence

When I highlight the words "Initial sentence" and copy them, they bring the "1. " with them.

When I go to Notepad and paste, I get:
1. Initial sentence
rather than what I expect and desire:
Initial sentence

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Word from Including Bullet Letter when Copying Text](https://superuser.com/questions/385001/prevent-word-from-including-bullet-letter-when-copying-text)

Comment: Also, behavior is the same in Outlook, so probably all Office apps as well (also in version 2013).

Answer (score 6):

You mentioned about getting numbering when pasting in to Word 2010. This at least is fixable.

1. File -> Options -> Advanced
2. Scroll down to the "Cut, copy, and paste" section
3. Turn off "Keep bullets and numbers when pasting text with Keep Text Only option

Now, when you paste with "Keep Text Only", you'll get the text without numbering.

Building on Radoo's suggestion, you could:

- keep a junk Word document open
- paste your copied text into this, with Keep Text Only
- select the text and copy it
- then paste it into Notepad

The main advantage of this is that it avoids perturbing the formatting of your original document.

(Aside: I had thought [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) would have helped, but when pasting list items from Word, into Notepad, the numbering is still included in this case)

Answer (score 3):

Select the list, disable bullets/numbering from MS Word, Copy, then Paste. Then undo in MS Word.

If you want to copy just one line, then it's easier, just select the line **without the ending space**, Copy, then Paste.