# Copy text from a list in an Outlook message without copying the list

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How do I copy text from lists without extra invisible characters polluting my clipboard?

With the following text selection copied <sub>(not using double-click because it selects the trailing newline)</sub>,

[image]

it pastes junk:

[image]

As a software developer, selection auto-expansion drives me *nuts* so it was one of the very first settings I tracked down to disable (along with [smart quotes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-curly-quotes-to-straight-quotes-and-vice-versa-017963a0-bc5f-486b-9c9d-0ec511a8fb8f?ocmsassetID=HA010173242&CorrelationId=fb51d466-af79-47a3-8cbf-33605c390bfc&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BM10)).

[image]

<sub>I tested the "Use Normal Style for bulletted or numbered lists" option</sub>

**Is there another setting that controls this behavior?**

Thanks.

P.S. Using Office 2013

<sub>P.P.S. The highlighted KB number does not exist in the [update catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com) but I found it as an Windows event saying it configured an update. How is this possible? Perhaps an unannounced security hotfix?</sub>

Comment: It appears to be, but [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1199418/207006) suggesting using alt-selection in Outlook is really janky and keeps opening the Research pane. Also, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/862375/207006) is incorrect as it is the exact thing I'm doing. As well, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1264839/207006) is also incorrect because the bullet is still pasted into legacy Notepad and standard HTML input fields.
Feel free to close my question/delete this comment though if the [hackish workaround](https://superuser.com/a/385003/207006) is the only working thing.

Comment: And still, this is a duplicate because of Word nature of Outlook email editor.